# Do custom collections work with ServiceStack's TypeSerializer?

Tags: .net, serialization, servicestack

I'm using @mythz's ServiceStack.Text (package version 2.9) TypeSerializer for serialization and deserialization to deep-copy objects in a cache.  I find myself getting this error on deserialization:

> Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type
>   'MetadataCollection', got string starting with: []

Where MetadataCollection is our custom collection class that implements IEnumerable.  I look at the serialized string for my test, and the Metadata property (type MetadataCollection) property on my serializer is indeed serialized as:

```
,Metadata:[],
```

Which seems correct to me, since this collection is empty.  Is there something I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a bug/missing feature in ServiceStack.Text package version 2.x.  I upgraded to ServiceStack.Text package version 3.9.3 and all is well.

Answer (score 1):

When you see errors like:

> Type definitions should start with a '{',

This is an indication that the shape of your Models doesn't match the JSON.

Can you provide a stand-alone failing test of an example that doesn't work?

Comment: Every test I try works--the deserializer handles it without throwing an exception.  I'm going to have to start with my huge code and whittle it down.

Comment: Looks like this is a problem in ServiceStack 2.9.  I'll have look a little further to confirm.